# What does "ranking a list" mean?

Tags: python

For a homework assignment I am given this task:

Read a list of numbers and generate a new list which squares the members of the original list.

generate a third list of ints that ranks the second list of ints.

What does it mean to "rank the list"? What is this asking me to do?

I am NOT asking for a solution to the programming assignment, please do not provide one.

Comment: Why don't you ask the person who posed the assignment? They should be able to tell you. All we can do is guess.

Comment: it probably asks to sort the list

Comment: a ranked list in this context can be a sorted one.

Comment: Ranking means adding the position of each number in a sorted list. Like ranking the players in a competition -- the winner is #1, next place is #2, and so on.

Comment: @xdurch0 This is a timed assignment that I can only submit once, so I will ask after but that isn't going to help me right now as my instructor is unavailable at the moment.

Comment: Please do not vandalize posts, including your own. If you are worried that you'll get in trouble for cheating on your homework, you should not have posted it on a public site.

Answer (score 1):

- To create a list of integers between 0 and N, a solution is to use the range(N) function.
- Then you can use the append() method which adds an item to the end of the list while getting the square of each element.
- Finally use the sort() method which sorts the list ascending by default. You can also make a function to decide the sorting criteria(s)

```
def printSortedList():
    l = list()
    for i in range(1,21):
        l.append(i**2)
    l.sort()
    print(l)
        
printSortedList()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ranking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking) means to number the items in a list from lowest to highest, or vice-versa.

So, for example, “ranking” the list `[639, 810, 150, 162, 461, 853, 648]` produces the list `[4, 6, 1, 2, 3, 7, 5]`, where `1` corresponds to the lowest value (150), `2` to the next-lowest value (162).

Or maybe you're supposed to rank them the other way, giving `[4, 2, 7, 6, 5, 1, 3]`.

Comment: Am important aspect of ranking not mentioned in the Wikipedia article is that some kind of metric gets used to measure it for each of the items, and that can be virtually *anything* — and it is a crucial piece of information not in the OP's question, so only guesses can be made.